# Point cloud 2D binarization

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, point-clouds

We divide the space into two-dimensional bins along the OXY plane. In each bin, we take the point with the smallest Z.

`points_cloud = np.array([` 
`[-2251.94719472, 1726.73267327,  4142.1],`  
`[-2251.94719472,  1726.73267327,  3000.2],` 
`[-2251.94719472 ,  1726.73267327,  1392.1],` 
`...,`  
`[ 1143.11620636,  -861.84471079,  100.12],`  
`[ 1143.11620636,  -861.84471079,  2076.89],`  
`[ 1143.11620636,  -861.84471079,  1800.11]])`

I only need to use NumPY or SciPY.
It should turn out this:

`points_min_z = np.array([` 
`[-2251.94719472 ,  1726.73267327,  1392.1],` 
`...,` 
`[ 1143.11620636,  -861.84471079,  100.12]])`

I tried this:

`vals, idx_start, count = np.unique(points_3D[:, [0, 1]],` 
                                   `return_counts=True,`
                                   `return_index=True,`
                                   `axis=0)`
`mask = [points_3D[:, [0, 1]] == i for i in vals]`

but it's too slow

I tried also from scipy binned_statistic_2d, but bins are only int

Please, help me!
I do not know how to solve this...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I created small example and binned then calculated the minimum z:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.random.randint(0, 35, (120, 3))

x = d[:, 0]

y = d[:, 1]

z = d[:, 2]

avg_dist = 5
xi = np.arange(x.min(), x.max(), avg_dist)
yi = np.arange(y.min(), y.max(), avg_dist)
zi = np.arange(z.min(), z.max(), avg_dist)

bins = [[[] for i in range(len(xi)+1)] for j in range(len(yi)+1)]
x_binned = (x/5).astype(int)
y_binned = (y/5).astype(int)
min_z = 99999
for i in range(len(z)):
    bins[x_binned[i]][y_binned[i]].append(z[i])
for i in range(len(xi)+1):
    for j in range(len(yi)+1):
        if len(bins[i][j]) == 0:
            bins[i][j] = np.nan
        else:
            bins[i][j] = np.min(bins[i][j])
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this is too slow an implementation, I have already described a similar one above.

Comment: look at this answer of mine:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644656/converting-3d-point-cloud-to-a-2d-gridmap-on-python/73913607#73913607

I am using scipy here but interpolation types doesnot have minimum but it is faster than what I wrote. Also if you want faster try cython or maybe even c++ unfortunately python is not a fast language.

Another thing when you ask question instead of explaining things that you tried try to put code snippets always. And better examples.